# Circular linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, circular-list

Let me know if it seems right to you and if anything can be optimized. My concern is that I'm unsure if circular linked lists are supposed to have a tail. I've implemented it just using a head. Is that wrong? If so, how would you change it to make it proper?

```
/* 
 * Circular Linked List
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void insert_beg_of_list(Node *current, int data);
void delete(Node *current, int data);
void print_list(Node *current);
int find_in_a_list(Node *current, int data);

void insert_beg_of_list(Node *current, int data) {
    //keep track of first node
    Node *head = current;

    while(current->next != head) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    current = current->next;
    current->data = data;
    current->next = head;

}

void delete_from_list(Node *current, int data) {

    Node *head = current;
    while(current->next != head && (current->next)->data != data) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    if(current->next == head) {
        printf("%d element is not found\n\n", data);
        return;
    }
    Node *tmp;
    tmp = current->next;
    current->next = tmp->next;
    free(tmp);  
    return;
}

void print_list(Node *current) {

    Node *head = current;
    current = current->next;
    while(current != head){
        printf(" %d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

}

int find_in_a_list(Node *current, int data) {

    Node *head = current;
    current = current->next;
    while(current != head) {
        if(current->data == data) {
            // Key found
            return 1;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    // Key is not found
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    Node *head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->next = head;  

    int data = 0;
    int usr_input = 0;

    while(1){
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        printf("1. Insert\n");
        printf("2. Delete\n");
        printf("3. Print\n");
        printf("4. Find\n");


        scanf("%d", &usr_input);

        // can also use a switch instead
        if( usr_input == 0) {
            exit(0);

        } else if(usr_input == 1) {
            printf("\nEnter an element you want to insert: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            insert_beg_of_list(head, data);

        } else if(usr_input == 2) {
            printf("\nEnter an element you want to delete: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            delete_from_list(head, data);

        } else if( usr_input == 3) {
            printf("The list is ");
            print_list(head);
            printf("\n\n");

        } else if( usr_input == 4) {
            printf("\nEnter an element you want to find: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            int is_found = find_in_a_list(head, data);
            if (is_found) {
                printf("\nElement is found\n\n");
            } else {
                printf("\nElement is NOT found\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a circular linked list should always have both a head and a tail.  The head is where to add/write next, the tail is where to delete/read next.  This means there should be a separate head pointer and a separate tail pointer.  those pointers keep track of the end of the circular linked list

Answer (score 4):

1. When making a collection of routines to handle a type, strongly advise to create a create and destroy function.   Rather then the below, consider some initialization function.

   ```
   // Replace this code
   Node *head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   head->next = head;  

   // with this
   Node *new_list(void ) {
     Node *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
     if (head) {
       head->next = head;
     }   
     return head;
   }  
   ...
   Node *head = new_list();
   ```
2. The names on the functions benefit by having the *leading* text indicate the grouping.   Avoid function `delete()` - too generic.

   ```
   void clist_insert_beg(Node *current, int data);
   void clist_delete(Node *current, int data);
   void clist_print(Node *current);
   int clist_find(Node *current, int data);
   ```
3. Consider 4 operations: Add_Before_First(), Remove_First(), Append(), Remove_End().   A circular list means it is relatively easy (O(1)) to do *something* at both ends of the list.   This code's `delete_from_list()` is nothing more that a typical linked list would do and take O(n) time.  Sadly even the `insert_beg_of_list()` also takes O(n) time.  Recommend to re-work this code so at least 1 of 2 "head" functions and at least 1 of the "tail" functions can operate in O(1) time  (no while loops).
4. Having a circular list with only a single pointer is do-able and perform 3 of the above 4 in O(1) time.  Consider a list that points to the tail.  No need for a head pointer as tail->next is the head.
5. Recommend a simpler to code and maintain allocation style.  The cast is not needed and the `sizeof` works even is the type of `*(current->next)` changes.

   ```
   // current->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   current->next = malloc(sizeof *(current->next));
   ```
6. Though posted as 1 file, better to post as a `circular_list.c`, `circular_list.h`, `main_sample_usage.c` files to clearly identify that which is public and private.
7. I have doubts `delete_from_list()` works when the last element is deleted.  I think that is because of the overall design.  IMO, when a list contains no data, it should consume minimal space.  IOW, a `NULL` pointer is an empty list.  When a list type is used heavily, there are often *many* empty lists.  So an empty list of a pointer to a node pointing to itself seems wasteful.
8. Functions that do not modify the list should use `const`.

   ```
   // int find_in_a_list(Node *current, int data) {
   int find_in_a_list(const Node *current, int data) {

   // void print_list(Node *current) {
   void print_list(const Node *current) {
   ```
9. Hoping to find functions like

   ```
   unsigned count_list(const Node *current);
   bool empty_list(const Node *current);
   ```
10. Minor Use `int main(void) {`